# Performance counter inaccurate in C#

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am working on a project that is collecting data about performance, like the Performance Monitor does.

However, when I running a monitor on pages/sec, it is givning a different result than the Performance Monitor.
I am thinking it is because the performance counter not giving all the decimals, and the average calculation becomes inaccurate.

My code UPDATED:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Management;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace PerformanceMonitor
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
       List<float> pagesSec = new List<float>();
        PerformanceCounter memoryPages = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Pages/sec");

        while (count < 50)
        {
            pagesSecValue = memoryPages.NextValue();
            pagesSec.Add(pagesSecValue);


           Console.WriteLine("Pages: " + pagesSecValue);
           count++;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Clear();
        }

Console.WriteLine("Avg pages/sec: " + pagesSec.Average());

 Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
}
```

While running the program, most of the time I get 0 printed on the console.

Results:
My program: 4,06349
Windows Performance Monitor: 12,133

Why the difference?

Comment: The reason this counter is inaccurate is because of how you decided to code it. If you are getting a 0 then you are doing something wrong.  Please post how exactly this loop is being called.  I have to downvote this question due to your lack of research before asking it.

Comment: @Ramhound I find your first two sentences ridiculously axiomatic. Obviously something is wrong, and of course it is a result of how the OP coded it. Otherwise they would not be asking for help. I don't understand what about this question demonstrates a lack of research in your eyes, or what code you are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing different calculations than the performance counter.  What you're doing is getting the pages per second once a second for 50 seconds and getting the average of those 50 numbers.  One, clearly the performance counter is working with data for a longer period of time.  Two, this isn't a useful average.  The performance counter is effectively taking a much higher sample.  For example, what do you think would happen if the pages per second values did this over a period of 2 seconds:
0    .5    1    1.5    2
5    15    6    20     4

And your code sampled at 0, 1 and 2 seconds?  Your "average" would be 5 and the performance counter (if it sampled at .5 seconds, which it doesn't) would be 10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now my sample rate is every 100ms and gives a result that is more equel to Windows Performance Monitor value.